# Direct page links with variables don't work. React/Nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I have an issue with my React website where pages with variables in their URL when accessed directly return a blank page. For example, it works fine if I have a URL like this: http://support.lifplatforms.com/new_post. But if I have a URL that looks like this: http://support.lifplatforms.com/view_post/d1d29e69-bca5-44b1-ba7b-997a3bfea087, It doesn't work. The only difference is that the last item in the URL: d1d29e69-bca5-44b1-ba7b-997a3bfea087, is not a page, but rather a variable. When looking at the sources section of the dev tools I think I can see why. It appears as if my webserver thinks that "view_post" is a folder instead of a page, and "d1d29e69-bca5-44b1-ba7b-997a3bfea087" is a file.

[image]

I'm Not entirely sure if this is a problem with Nginx or my react site. It's worth noting that everything works fine in a development environment. It only has issues with the production version. It's also worth noting that I tried using gserve and I had the same issues so it may have something to do with my React app.

**React Route Structure**

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/">
      <Routes>
        <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Main />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/new_post" element={<NewPost />} />
        <Route path="/search/:query" element={<Search />} />
        <Route path="/view_post/:post_id" element={<ViewPost />} />
      </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**Nginx Config**

```
server {
    server_name support.lifplatforms.com;
    root /var/www/support.lifplatforms.com;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    }

    location ~ \.js$ {
        types { application/javascript js; }
        add_header Content-Type application/javascript;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you see the HTTP status code of this request?

Comment: Well when it’s looking for the file to render the page it returns a 404 because it’s looking in a folder that doesn’t exist